# Add a buffer to geospatial point on map in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial

I have a ggplot map with a location and would like to add a buffer (spatialPolygon) around this location. However, when I add the buffer to my ggplot, I get the error "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found.".  I am not sure where to go from here.

my code

```
library(sp)
library(geosphere)
library(geobuffer)
library(ggplot2)
library(rworldmap)
library(rworldxtra)

# my location
colony.df <- data.frame(Long = c(-61.313002), Lat = c(-51.714750)) # keep as dataframe for map
colony <- data.frame(Long = c(-61.313002), Lat = c(-51.714750)) # transform for buffer


# Convert location dataframe to spatial points (SpatialPointsDataFrame)
coordinates(colony) <- cbind(colony$Long, colony$Lat)

# assign a CRS to the spatial object
proj4string(colony) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0") 

# create buffer around the colony
buf10km<- geobuffer_pts(xy = colony, dist_m = 10000)

# load shapefiles for ggplot

worldMap <- rworldmap::getMap(resolution = "high")
fi <- worldMap[which(worldMap$NAME == "Falkland Is."), ]


# create ggplot

p <- ggplot(colony.df) +
  # countries
  geom_polygon(data = fi, aes(long, lat, group = group), color = "grey20", fill = "grey60", size = 0.3) +
  # data
  geom_point(aes(x = Long, y = Lat), size = 3) +
  # visuals
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(5), name = "Longitude (W)", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(5), name = "Latitude (S)", expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_quickmap(xlim = c(-64,-60), ylim = c(-50,-53)) + # zoomed out
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, vjust = 0),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, vjust = 2),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
p

# add buffer
p <- p + geom_polygon(aes(x=x, y=y), data = buf10km, color = "red", alpha = 0.2, size = .2)

p
```

Answer (score 4):

One option using `sf` rather than `sp`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1

worldMap <- rworldmap::getMap(resolution = 'high')
fi <- worldMap[which(worldMap$NAME == "Falkland Is."), ]


colony <- data.frame(Long = c(-61.313002), Lat = c(-51.714750))

colony_sf <- colony %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('Long', 'Lat')) %>%
  st_set_crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")


colony_10km <-  st_buffer(colony_sf, units::as_units(10, 'kilometer'))


ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = fi, 
               aes(long, lat, group = group), 
               color = "grey20", 
               fill = "grey60", 
               size = 0.3) +
  geom_sf(data = colony_10km, fill = 'blue') +
  geom_sf(data = colony_sf, color = 'red')
#> Regions defined for each Polygons
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: +1 definitely better to use `sf`. If OP had to stick with `sp` for some reason, they could use `rgeos::gBuffer()` and a projected coordinate system.

Comment: That's a very smooth way, of doing this thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone wanted to stick with `sp` rather than switching to `sf`, the issue with the original code was that the buffer polygon first needed to be converted back to a data.frame using `fortify` before being usable in a ggplot:

```
# covert geospatial buffer polygon to a shapefile
buf10km.df <- fortify(buf10km)

# add buffer
p <- p + geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat), data = buf10km.df, color = "red", alpha = .2, size = .2)
```